# How to handle numerous combinations of screen sizes and densities?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-drawable, dpi

I'm struggling with getting the right `drawables` onto the right screen. I followed the android developer instructions and created a version per `drawable` for `ldpi` through `xxhdpi`. However, physically small and large screens with the same `dpi` select the same `drawable`, where I'd like the larger screen to get a bigger one.

The layouts are pretty straight forward, so I don't think I need to create new ones with different qualifiers, so I need to come up with a good way to categorise `drawables` (and/or screen resolutions). I'm guessing it's done with the `sw<N>dp` qualifier or one of it's siblings, but how do I choose the intervals? I've seen examples (`sw600dp`, `w820dp`, etc) but no guidelines for how to determine them. Do I need to do it by trial-and-error on different AVD configurations, and which are the best to do so with?

How do I scale my drawables when I've determined which `-sw<N>dp` to use? Do I follow the standard `3:4:6:8:12:16` or something else?

Yet again, the `sw<N>dp` qualifiers don't seem to be for `drawables`, since they get scaled weirdly and blurry as a result. Do I instead use `layouts` with the qualifiers, but how? I'm really at a loss here...

Comment: You misunderstand how drawables, layouts, screensize and resolution interact. Drawables are in resolution buckets *exactly* because if they weren't, you would see "blurry" assets and such. Putting drawables in size-buckets is positively the wrong thing to do. You will need to create drawables in different sizes, and then create size-specific layouts to select them. Alternatively, you could create oversized drawables and size-specific dimensions to scale down. I very seldom find the need to create more than two size-specific layouts (phone and tablet), and I never adjust the size of drawables.

Answer (score 0):

> However, physically small and large screens with the same dpi select the same drawable, where I'd like the larger screen to get a bigger one.

Put the smaller ones in `res/drawable-...dpi/` directories, for varying values of `...` (e.g., `x`). Put the larger ones in `res/drawable-swNNNdp-...dpi/`, for varying values of `NNN` (e.g., `800`) and `...`. Note that the `-swNNNdp` qualifier has to be in the name before the `-...dpi` qualifier.

> but how do I choose the intervals?

That's up to you. You are the one who is saying that "I'd like the larger screen to get a bigger one". Only you know what you like, and only you know where the cutoff is between "larger" and not-"larger" is in your mind. There is no universal answer for this, just as there is no universal answer for when you change the layout of a Web page to be "mobile" or not.

> Do I need to do it by trial-and-error on different AVD configurations, and which are the best to do so with?

I would recommend that you try it on hardware.

If you decide that you want larger images on 7" tablets and up, `-sw600dp` would be a reasonable choice. If you decide that you want larger images on 10" tablets and up, `-sw720dp` would be a reasonable choice. Beyond that, break out a ruler and measure the shortest screen width, then multiply by 160 to get dpi. Google also maintains [a database of many popular devices](https://design.google.com/devices/), with the dimensions in `px` and `dpi` for each.

> How do I scale my drawables when I've determined which -swdp to use?

Again, that's up you. If you decide that you want the images to be 50% bigger on the larger screens, create your images that are 50% bigger. Again, you are the one who is saying "I'd like the larger screen to get a bigger one". Only you know what you like, and only you know what "bigger" would mean to get you to something that you like.